# com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Tags: appium, appium-android

I have the following code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SampleSauceCheckBoxTest {

    public static final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
    public static AndroidDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "\\Users\\jsun\\Downloads\\app-debug.apk");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(URL), capabilities);

        /**
         * Test Actions here...
         */
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        MobileElement mbeLogin = (MobileElement)driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Log In']");
        mbeLogin.click();

        //driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

> C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
>   2018.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57587:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\dev\java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\work\SauceLabsTest\out\production\SauceLabsTest;C:\work\SauceLabsTest\lib\refined\java-client-3.4.0.jar;C:\work\SauceLabsTest\lib\refined\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
>   SampleSauceCheckBoxTest Nov 21, 2018 2:40:07 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: W3C Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be
>   converted to WebElement: {element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=1} Build
>   info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System
>   info: host: 'L5480X2M2S5M2', ip: '10.166.43.162', os.name: 'Windows
>   10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:509)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:132)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)  at SampleSauceCheckBoxTest.main(SampleSauceCheckBoxTest.java:34)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebElement    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:415)
>     ... 5 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

The code worked fine before, so that's not the problems about appium/selenium versions compatibility.

Comment: Put the error output into a quote block for readability

Answer (score 1):

From the logs I can understand that you need to use generic AndroidDriver with type MobileElement. So in your code change the following line as,

```
AndroidDriver <MobileElement> driver = null;
```

Also remove casting to MobileElement done while finding the element.

**Edit:**
Also make sure to use latest Appium Java client and Selenium.

Comment: What version of Appium server, Java client and selenium are you using? Make sure you are using latest stable version of all.

Comment: Selenium and Appium are both using 3.4. And Selenium Java is also using 3.4

Comment: It works now. I changed the Selenium and Selenium Java versions to 3.14. And Appium to 6.1